# Obtain energy current density from heat diffusion equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

The heat diffusion equation is $$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}=D\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2}$$

To obtain de energy current density we can start off from Fourier's law in 1D:

$$q = -k\frac{dT}{dx},$$

where $k$ is the thermal conductivity. Therefore,

$$\frac{\partial q}{\partial x} = -k \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2}$$

How would this derivation follow in order to obtain the energy current density $j$? Please, could you give me any hint?

Thanks.

Comment: can you elaborate what exactly is your question? first equation is just 1d heat diffusion pde and you mentioned where second one comes from, and third one is just its derivative, what derivation do you mean by **this derivation**? (also Fourier's law states $q = -k \nabla T$ so it's partial derivative in second equation)

Comment: I meant by "this derivation" the derivation to obtain the energy current density $j$.

Comment: To convert from thermal conductivity to energy current density, you need the material density and the heat capacity.

Comment: Thanks! But those magnitudes are implicit in the diffusivity D, aren't they?

Comment: Technically their product is: $D=k/(\rho C)$. I think to convert you need one or the other separately, but I'm not being super careful with my dimensional analysis to be sure.

Comment: Certainly. But how could I derive the energy current density expression from the diffusion equation?

Comment: If you have a rod with uniform cross section and uniform thermal parameters other than temperature, then I think the energy current density along the rod is just $q$ divided by the cross sectional area. Either that or just $q$ itself.